# Could not set output in Github Action

Tags: powershell, github-actions

I am using Powershell script inside Github Action to manage state and compilation of application but lately something happened with `GITHUB_OUTPUT` parameter. I was using it as:

```yaml
steps:
      -
        name: Create folders
        id: create-folders
        run: |

          if ((Test-Path -Path ${{ env.ARTIFACTS_OUTPUT_FOLDER }} -PathType Container) -eq $false) {
            New-Item -Path ${{ env.ARTIFACTS_OUTPUT_FOLDER }} -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
          }
          Write-Output "Created artifact output folder: ${{ env.ARTIFACTS_OUTPUT_FOLDER }}"

          ...
          ...
         Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Value "root_path=$rootPath\${{ env.ARTIFACTS_OUTPUT_FOLDER }}"
```

but now I receive an error:

```
Line |
  81 |  Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Value "root_path=$rootPath\ …
     |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

All my workflows start to fail because of this.

Is there any other way to pass data between steps of workflow ?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider setting [`GITHUB_ENV` instead](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files):

```yaml
$rootPathValue = "root_path=$rootPath\${{ env.ARTIFACTS_OUTPUT_FOLDER }}"
      echo "root_path=$rootPathValue" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

And then using it in your other job:

```yaml
steps:
  -
    name: Use the output value from previous step
    run: |
      echo "The root path is: $env:root_path"
```

---

Using the same idea, GITHUB_OUTPUT should work with:

```yaml
echo "root_path=$rootPathValue" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

And:

```yaml
steps:
  -
    name: Use the output value from previous step
    run: |
      $rootPath = (Get-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT | Select-String -Pattern "^root_path=").ToString().Split("=")[1]
      echo "The root path is: $rootPath"
```

Comment: It seems to be working OK

Do you know what heppened to `GITHUB_OUTPUT` variable ? It is used in about 200,000 repositories on Github

Comment: @AlexF Great! Would that answer your question?

Comment: ??? What kinda question is that ?? What 'great' about my question ? Are you a ChatGPT bot ?

Comment: @AlexF I was just answering your initial comment which was: "It seems to be working OK" (which is what the "Great" was referring to). I missed your edit.

Comment: @AlexF "Do you know what happened to `GITHUB_OUTPUT` variable ? It is used in about 200,000 repositories on GitHub": I have edited the answer to illustrate the same idea, using this time `GITHUB_OUPUT`.

Comment: It seems now that `GITHUB_OUTPUT` back to work... At least Powershell does not throw when assign something to this. It is still can not pass between steps (all references to steps output completely deleted from my script by Github parser or something)

So I guess it is temporary glitch at Github... I hope so.... Thanks anyway

Comment: @AlexF True, there was a [recent incident involving GitHub Actions](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/lhw4ny5js29b).